# Searching objects by pressing button in django

Tags: python, html, django, search

I want to create a search form but using button instead of text input.

I have a table with categories and each category has a button that leads to subcategories that share this category. When I click the button I somehow want to send name of the category to the view and filter subcategories that will be then rendered to specific template.

Here is my template:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Category name</th>
         <th>Updated at</th>
         <th>Subcategories</th>
         <th>Edit</th>
         <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      {% for category in categories %}
         <tr>
            <td>{{category.id}}</td>
            <td>{{category.name}}</td>
            <td>{{category.updated|date:"d.m.Y G:i:s"}}</td>
            <td><a href="#">Subcategories</a></td>    <!-- This link should be modified -->
            <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
         </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

So as you can see I have a link 'Subcategories' which should open subcategory page where I will display all subcategories of that category

Here is my models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Subcategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Subcategories'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have no idea how to do this. I'm glad to hear any suggestions about this problem. Thanks!

Comment: You could create a page that takes a category id as parameter, and then on that page you display all subcategories of the category from teh parameter. Then the link becomes something like subcategories/category.id

Comment: So I tried to send id of the category in from link: {%url 'subcategories' category.id%}. Then in views.py I get this id. Now I don't know how to find that category by category.id.  views.py: `def subcategories(request, pk):
    subcategories = Subcategory.objects.get(category=)` In models category is a ForeignKey

Comment: that needs to be done by your view. something along the way: Subcategory.Objects.find(category=Your ParentCategory)

Comment: either you get the category first Category.Objects.get(pk=pk) or Subcategory.objects.find(category__id=pk)

Comment: So I found the way. I separated them to all subcategories(when they aren't filtered) and subcategoriesFiltered(when button is clicked). So in subcategoriesFiltered I first get the category: `category = Category.objects.get(id=pk)`, then I pass this variable into filter method: `subategories = Subcategories.objects.filter(category=category)`. Method `.get` didn't work and was throwing an error saying "get() returned more than 1 Category -- it returned 2!". So `.filter` fixed this. Thank you very much for your help!